# Submit django form in a modal popup

Tags: python, jquery, django

I render my form inside a modal:

view:

```
@login_required
def task_edit(request, pk):
    member = get_object_or_404(Tasks, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TasksForm(request.POST or None, instance=member)
        if form.is_valid():
            reg = form.save(commit=False)
            reg.save()
            return HttpResponse(
                '<script type="text/javascript">window.close();</script>')
    else:
        form = TasksForm(instance=member)
    return render(request, 'TaskProj/task_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

my html rendered in a modal popup:

```
{%load staticfiles %}
 <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <div class="panel">
                <div class="content-box">
    <h3 class="content-box-header bg-primary">

                         <span class="icon-separator">
                                <i class="glyph-icon icon-tasks"></i>
                            </span>
                       <span class="header-wrapper">
 Eidt Tasks                      </span>

                      </span>

                        </h3>
    <div class="panel">
<div class="panel-body">
    <form method="POST" id="form" class="form-horizontal bordered-row" autocomplete="off">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="example-box-wrapper">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                </div>
             </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salva</button>
       </div>
    </div>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click','.submit',function(){
    $( "#form" ).submit();
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

This form is rendered inside a modal popup. 
I try to save, it close modal but not save form.
I think there is a problem with submit button...
Any idea?
TY

Comment: add a class "submit" in your button. script is '.submit', so form will be submitted when submit button has a class "submit"

Comment: I tryed: `$(document).on('click','.submit',function(){
    $( "#form" ).submit();
});` ; it close modal but not save...

Comment: Are you doing anything in the script? If no, then simply remove the script

Comment: To summarize: 1) the click handler is bound to an element with class "submit", but no such element exists. 2) The submit button will submit the form, so the JavaScript doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: @showdev The form is inside a modal dialog popup, I tryed without script but nothing happen

Comment: It might help to build a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue, using the rendered HTML code. It also looks like your HTML is malformed (e.g. there are some unmatched `</div>` tags before the closing `</form>`), which could be causing problems.

Comment: in form try  method="post" instead of  method="POST". Don't know if this will work. Print something inside this condition if request.method == "POST": to check if this True or not.

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare an action attribute with the url to your function that handles the specific form in views.py. So that the form knows where to go, and be handled:

```
 <form method="POST" id="form" class="form-horizontal bordered-row" action="{% 'task_edit' your-object.pk %}" autocomplete="off">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="example-box-wrapper">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                </div>
             </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salva</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```